# How to create list from different length of lists using condition in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, conditional-statements

I have a list of 9 lists, inside every lists there are few elements. Every elements are string. Now I want to create another list of lists based upon partially similar string. I can do that individually, without using conditional statement. But I want to do it using if condition.

What I have tried :

```
var = ["pr", "tas", "ts"]

prs = []
for i in all_files:
    for j in i:
        if var[0] in j:
            prs.append(j)
            
tass = []
for i in all_files:
    for j in i:
        if var[1] in j:
            tass.append(j)
            
tss = []
for i in all_files:
    for j in i:
        if var[2] in j:
            tss.append(j)
```

In the above way I can do that thing. But I want to loop over **var** as well. For that I have tried :

```
gg = []            
for i in all_files:
    for j in i:
        for k in var[0:3]:
            kk = []
            if k in j:
                kk.append(j)
        gg.append(kk)
```

It is giving a list, but there are so many blank lists inside that list. I want all the "pr" containing file would be in a list, same for "ts" and "tas" and they will be inside a list. Please let me know if anyone have any doubt Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want empty `kk` lists to be appended to `gg`, check if `kk` is empty before you append it to `gg`

Comment: To clarify: you have three "condititions", `"pr"`, `"tas"`, and `"ts"`, and you want to sort an iterable of `all_files` into three separate lists based on whether or not the file (presumably, rather the file **name**) contains one of those three strings?

Comment: You are correct. Let me give you a little bit more insight. all_files contains 9 list, each list have file names contain those three strings  "pr", "tas", and "ts". Please let me know it it clarifies or not. Thanks @JRiggles

Comment: In the interest of clarity and providing a complete [mre], you should include sample input data in your question. I added some sample data to my answer based on your comment above, but in the future please add this when you ask the question.

Comment: This is essentially a ["variable variables" question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/984421), with the answer being to use a `dict`. Thus, in your second example, do `gg = {k: [] for k in var}` and then `if k in j: gg[k].append(j)`. This will give the same result as your first example, except that e.g. the variable `prs` becomes `gg['prs']`. This should be a lot easier to work with than having lots of separate variables (and you can also easily get a list of lists with `list(gg.values())`).

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience caused by me @PranavHosangadi

Comment: You suggestion worked @ekhumoro. I did a little bit of modification as I need list, so the code that I have used as follows :

```lang-py   
gg = [[] for k in var]  
for i in all_files:  
    for j in i:  
        for k in var:  
            if k in j:  
                gg[var.index(k)].append(j)  
```

Comment: @SWARNENDUPAL no inconvenience at all! FWIW, you shouldn't do `var.index(k)` because that's an extra loop hidden in the `.index` call. You already know the index of the iteration because you're the one doing the iteration, so use `enumerate` to get the index. At the end of the day you're trying to get the same index from `gg` as you are from `k`, so you might as well iterate over `zip(gg, k)`, which is what my code does.

Answer (score 0):

First, make a list `out` that contains one empty list for each element of `var`

```
var = ["pr", "tas", "ts"]
out = [[] for _ in var]
```

This is equivalent to creating the three empty lists `prs`, `tass`, and `tss`.

Then, when you iterate over `var`, also iterate over `out`, and append to that element of `out`.

```
for i in all_files:
    for j in i:
        for o, k in zip(out, var):
            if k in j:
                o.append(j)
```

In the `for o, k...` loop, when `k` is `"pr"`, `o` is the first list in `out` (`prs` in your old approach). When `k` is `"tas"`, `o` is the second list in `out` (`tass` in your old approach).

Trying this with some sample data:

```
all_files = [["pr0", "tas0", "ts0", "abc0"],
             ["pr10", "tas10", "ts10", "abc10"],
             ["pr20", "tas20", "ts20", "abc20"]]
```

gives:

```
out = [['pr0', 'pr10', 'pr20'], ['tas0', 'tas10', 'tas20'], ['ts0', 'ts10', 'ts20']]
```

The first element contains all the `pr` values, the second element contains all the `tas` values, etc.

You can unpack the `out` list into your separate variables if you really want:

```
prs, tass, tss = out
```

which gives:

```
prs = ['pr0', 'pr10', 'pr20']

tass = ['tas0', 'tas10', 'tas20']

tss = ['ts0', 'ts10', 'ts20']
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you should be using a dictionary for this instead of individual variables, you could combine the 3 loops using a list of variables that you pair up with the list of string patterns using zip():

```
prs, tass, tss = [], [], []      # individual variables (lists)
varList = [prs, tass, tss]       # list of variables
var     = ["pr", "tas", "ts"]    # corresponding string patterns

for aFile in all_files:                           # loop through files
    for line in aFile:                            # lines of each file
        for aList, pattern in zip(varList,var):   # variables and patterns
            if pattern in line:
                aList.append(line)                # tally matches
```

If you decide to use a dictionary, the loops could look like this:

```
patterns = {"prs":"pr", "tass":"ts", "tss":"ts"}
matches  = {k:[] for k in patterns}
for aFile in all_files:
    for line in aFile:
        for name,pattern in patterns.items():
            if pattern in line:
                matches[name].append(line)
```

You can then access individual lists using their name as a string: `matches['prs']`

If you find the brackets and quotes too cumbersome, you can create a special dictionary class of your own that allows more streamlined referencing:

```
class VarDict(dict): __getattr__ = dict.get
```

And use it for your matches:

```
matches  = VarDict({k:[] for k in patterns})
```

And then you can reference the matches more directly: `matches.prs`